# URL Pattern with Spring MVC and Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have seen some url-pattern in my xml e.g, in filter-mapping, intercept-url, mvc:resources, etc. Are these patterns always the same ? What's the difference among these URL patterns `/`, `/*`, `/**` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends in which context you ask this question:

1. Servlet/Filter mappings
2. Spring Security mappings

---

### Servlet/Filter mappings

> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for
>   path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>   application's context root, i.e., requests of the form `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In this case the path info is ’/’ and the servlet path and context path is
>   empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the
>   application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path
>   and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only

This comes from the [Servlet Specification (JSR 315)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) (section 12.2).

In a Servlet/Filter mapping scenario `/` means the "*default*" servlet, normally this is where the `DefaultServlet` (in Tomcat that is) is mapped to. Basically it handles all incoming requests and doesn't pass them on further down the chain for processing (basically this is the last-catch-all mapping).

`/*` in the servlet mapping scenario means all incoming URLs (when it cannot be processed it will be handed of the the last-catch-all-mapping).

---

### Spring Security mappings

Now when talking about **Spring**, `/`, `/*` and `/**` have a different meaning. They refer to so called Ant-style [path expressions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).

Where `/` means only / (the root of your application), where `/*` means the root including one level deep and where `/**` means everything.

So `/foo/*` will match a URL with `/foo/bar` but will not match `/foo/bar/baz`. Whereas `/**` or `/foo/**` would match all of them.

Comment: Are you saying that the pattern `/**` does not exist in Servlet/Filter ? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Only `/` and `/*` are valid there.

Comment: I've modified the answer to include part the part of the Servlet-spec that mentions the URL mappings.